# Creating Java Web Application programmatically

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat

I am thinking of using a Java web application to create a customised website,
1. so a user can specify the background image, css, etc 
2. user can specify other options
2. and at the end of the process, the user can download the WAR file, ready to be deployed wherever they wish.

So, what is the easiest way to programmatically create a Java web application to be deployed into Tomcat ?

Is there a framework that I can use or should I start from scratch ?

The following screenshots are taken from ArcGIS Server 10, where a user can create a new web application on the fly.

[image: Create a web app 1]
[image: Create a web app 2]
[image: Create a web app 3]

Comment: It will make more sense if you talk reverse. That is, _"I want to create a war that can be completely customized in it's look and feel."_ And, if it makes sense, you want to create a CMS in Java much like Joomla in PHP.

Comment: "I want to create a war that can be completely customized in it's look and feel." makes sense, and in a way the concept is similar to embedded CMS in a Java webapp?

Answer (score 4):

> so a user can specify the background image, css, etc

For all these there is no need of new war . it can be configured with the same web app.

All the things that you want to customized can come from DB

Comment: In terms of the question "and the end of the process, the user can download the WAR file." i assumed, that downloading a .war file is an important part of the process portoalet wants to achieve.

Comment: @Chris, If OP can do it without overhead of building new war for each request ,It would be far far better I think

Comment: The idea is for to produce a war file that can be directly deployed to another server by the user.

Comment: @portoalet You can have better solution, give one war to each user, and ask them for all these configuration at first load time from very well designed UI. this would be better solution I feel and store all the preferences in your DB.

Answer (score 3):

I think a .war file is nothing but a renamed .zip file which is following some conventions on the folder and file structure it contains.

So the easiest way to do this i think is geneate a filestructure, packing it into a .zip file and rename it. You could first create a "template" file structure by hand, copy it and modify the contents you want.

I think any framework would be overkill here.

Comment: Yes, zip-ing it all and renaming to war would be totally enough. If you want some extra features - you can simply integrate ANT libraries and use them. ANT is a tool that among other features can also create any customized WAR with any structure you want using buildscripts.

Comment: hm ok so it seems i have to do it manually, i.e. inserting user specified images, css, js, and then packing it up as a zip(war) file.

Answer (score 1):

Did u check out [shrinkwrap](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ShrinkWrap) from boss community?
It's still alpha release but I think that might help u out.

Comment: thanks, shrinkwrap can help me building thing programmatically :)

Answer (score 0):

Set standards for the names/sizes of graphics, stylesheets, etc. and have the web app pull those from an external source (say another host on the same server).
E.g. your webapp would host under http://xxx.yyy.zzz/webapp and the resources sit in a separate directory/host on your server reachable under http://xxx.yyy.zzz/resources .